# Elasticsearch query speed up with repeated used terms query filter

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, filter, query-cache

I will need to find out the co-occurrence times between one single tag and another fixed set of tags as whole. I have 10000 different single tags, and there are 10k tags inside fixed set of tags. I loop through all single tags under a fixed set of tags context with a fixed time range. I have total 1 billion documents inside the index with 20 shards.

Here is the elasticsearch query, elasticsearch 6.6.0:

```
es.search(index=index, size=0, body={ 
        "query": {
          "bool": {
              "filter": [
                  {"range": {
                      "created_time": {
                       "gte": fixed_start_time,  
                       "lte": fixed_end_time, 
                       "format": "yyyy-MM-dd-HH"
                       }}},
                        {"term": {"tags": dynamic_single_tag}},
                        {"terms": {"tags": {
                            "index" : "fixed_set_tags_list",
                            "id" : 2,
                            "type" : "twitter",
                            "path" : "tag_list"
                        }}}
                       ]

                }
          }, "aggs": {
             "by_month": {
              "date_histogram": {
                  "field": "created_time",
                  "interval": "month",
                              "min_doc_count": 0,
                              "extended_bounds": {
                                  "min": two_month_start_time,
                                  "max": start_month_start_time}

              }}}
        })
```

My question: Is there any solution which can have a cache inside elasticsearch for a fixed 10k set of tags terms query and time range filter  which can speed up the query time? It took 1.5s for one single tag for my query above.

Comment: I would like to ask you few clarifying questions. How variable are the parameters (`fixed_start_time`, `fixed_end_time`, `two_month_start_time`, `start_month_start_time`)? Do they change with every request, daily, monthly? Is the set of tags (from which `dynamic_single_tag` is taken) the same as `fixed_set_tags_list`? How often do you need to repeat this kind of job - means, what is your desired performance, how much time is it ok for the entire 10K tags to be computed?

Comment: @Nikolay Vasiliev  I will need to perform 30k queries once on monthly based . so , fixed_start_time, fixed_end_time, two_month_start_time, start_month_start_time will be changed on monthly basis .  dynamic_single_tag is not in fixed_set_tags_list . In terms of performance , I have 30k queries , one query takes 1.5s , it will takes 12.5 hours to finish it . I desire it can be finish within 30mins or 1 hour .

Comment: I knew I can add more nodes , meanwhile , I'd like to know whether there is any query optimization first , such as filter cache in place for 1st set of fixed_set_tags_list , after 10k dynamic_single_tag query ,  then delete cache , then build up another filter cache for 2nd set of fixed_set_tags_list , and proceed with different dynamic_single_tag queries , and so on .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal behavior for Elasticsearch aggregations (actually, pretty good performance given that you have 1 billion documents).

There are a couple of options you may consider: using a batch of [`filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) aggregations, re-indexing with a subset of documents, and downloading the data out of Elasticsearch and computing the co-occurrences offline.

But probably it is worth trying to send those 10K queries and see if Elasticsearch built-in caching kicks in.

Let me explain in a bit more detail each of these options.

### Using `filter` aggregation

First, let's outline what we are doing in the original ES query:

- filter documents with `create_time` in certain time window;
- filter documents containing desired tag `dynamic_single_tag`;
- also filter documents who have at least one tag from the list `fixed_set_tags_list`;
- count how many such documents there are per each month in certain time period.

The performance is a problem because we've got 10K of tags to make such queries for.

What we can do here is to move `filter` on `dynamic_single_tag` from query to aggregations:

```
POST myindex/_doc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "terms": { ... } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by tag C": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "tags": "C" <== here's the filter
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by month": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "created_time",
            "interval": "month",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": "2019-01-01",
              "max": "2019-02-01"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result will look something like this:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "by tag C" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "by month" : {
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1546300800000,
            "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1548979200000,
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Now, if you are asking how this can help the performance, here is the trick: to add more such `filter` aggregations, for each tag: `"by tag D"`, `"by tag E"`, etc.

The improvement will come from doing "batch" requests, [combining many initial requests into one](https://www.elastic.co/blog/modeling-data-for-fast-aggregations). It might not be practical to put all 10K of them in one query, but even batches of 100 tags per query can be a game changer.

(Side note: roughly the same behavior can be achieved via [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation with [`include`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values) filter parameter.)

This method of course requires getting hands dirty and writing a bit more complex query, but it will come handy if one needs to run such queries at random times with 0 preparation.

### re-index the documents

The idea behind second method is to reduce the set of documents beforehand, via [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/docs-reindex.html). `reindex` query might look like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "myindex",
    "type": "_doc",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "range": {
              "created_time": {
                "gte": "fixed_start_time",
                "lte": "fixed_end_time",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd-HH"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "tags": {
                "index": "fixed_set_tags_list",
                "id": 2,
                "type": "twitter",
                "path": "tag_list"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "myindex_reduced"
  }
}
```

This query will create a new index, `myindex_reduced`, containing only elements that satisfy first 2 clauses of filtering.

At this point, the original query can be done without those 2 clauses.

The speed-up in this case will come from limiting the number of documents, the smaller it will be, the bigger the gain. So, if `fixed_set_tags_list` leaves you with a little portion of 1 billion, this is the option you can definitely try.

### Downloading data and processing outside Elasticsearch

To be honest, this use-case looks more like a job for [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). If data analytics is your case, I would suggest using [scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-scroll.html) to extract the data on disk and then process it with an arbitrary script.

In python it could be as simple as using [`.scan()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) helper method of `elasticsearch` library.

### Why not to try the brute force approach?

Elasticsearch will already try to help you with your query via [`request cache`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/shard-request-cache.html). It is applied only to pure-aggregation queries (`size: 0`), so should work in your case.

But it will not, because the content of the query will always be different (the whole [JSON of the query is used as caching key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/shard-request-cache.html#_cache_key), and we have a new tag in every query). A different level of caching will start to play.

[Elasticsearch heavily relies on the filesystem cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/tune-for-search-speed.html#_give_memory_to_the_filesystem_cache_2), which means that under the hood the more often accessed blocks of the filesystem will get cached (practically loaded into RAM). For the end-user it means that "warming up" will come slowly and with volume of similar requests.

In your case, aggregations and filtering will occur on 2 fields: `create_time` and `tags`. This means that after doing maybe 10 or 100 requests, with different tags, the response time will drop from 1.5s to something more bearable.

To demonstrate my point, here is a [Vegeta](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta) plot from my study of Elasticsearch performance under the same query with heavy aggregations sent with fixed RPS:

[image: Filesystem cache kicks in]

As you can see, initially the request was taking ~10s, and after 100 requests it diminished to brilliant 200ms.

I would definitely suggest to try this "brute force" approach, because if it works it is good, if it does not - it costed nothing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great thanks to your detailed comments !!! All options you mentioned sounds really inspiring .  I will try all options and let you know the results . P.S. especially for using pandas to perform this job is a great idea with out of box thinking .

Comment: I implemented the filter aggregation and put 4841 dynamic_single_tags into filter aggregations in one query . The performance is previous 89mins(loop 4841 dynamic_single_tags leads to 4841 queries ) VS 7mins(put 4841 dynamic_single_tags into filter aggs with one query ) . I found out more system RAM and reducing heap size will improve the performance a lot . I believe filter aggs is the solution I am going to implement . Thanks a lot .

Comment: Great, glad it helped!